# How to update table from a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting the sum of all columns with a select query. I want to update that data in the table itself, I want to add the data in the row where the name column is equal to 'Total'.

Here is what I have tried:

```
DECLARE @sum_query NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT 
    @sum_query = @sum_query + 'ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(' + QUOTENAME(column_name) + ') = 1 THEN CONVERT(Float, ' + QUOTENAME(column_name) + ') ELSE 0 END)/10000000, 0), '
FROM 
    information_schema.columns
WHERE 
    table_name = 'SqlInsertST2'
    AND ordinal_position > (SELECT ordinal_position
                            FROM information_schema.columns
                            WHERE table_name = 'SqlInsertST2'
                              AND column_name = 'Class');

SET @sum_query = LEFT(@sum_query, LEN(@sum_query) - 1); -- Remove trailing comma

SET @sum_query = 'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME('SqlInsertST2') + ' SET ' + LEFT(@sum_query, LEN(@sum_query) - 1) + ' WHERE Name = ''Total''';

EXEC sp_executesql @sum_query;
```

A sample output

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL at all here? Using a temporary table to `UPDATE` a table is no different to using a non-temporary table though; the syntax doesn't change because the table is temporary.

Comment: A tips when doing dynamic sql, first try to write out a working version of static sql with some columns, then try to achieve the same with dynamic. Another tip is to use PRINT command to see if your query works or not

Comment: beacuse there are 300 pus coulmns so i dont want to add all the coulmns manually

Comment: another tip is that SUM and UPDATe usually doesn't work at the same level, unless you use subquery or join your summarized data

Comment: please can u provide  a solution

Comment: I can, but you seem clever enough, i think you can figure out the problem

Comment: As @siggemannen noted, using `PRINT` statement just before `EXEC sp_executesql` is the key. It will show you the actual query.

Comment: here is the print statement for one coulmn , UPDATE [SqlInsertST2] SET 
[English]  = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([English]) = 1 THEN CONVERT(Float, [English]) ELSE 0 END)/10000000, 0)
WHERE [Name] = 'Total'

Comment: here is full print statement with a sample data , https://ctxt.io/2/AACQPTfeEQ

Comment: Looks like @Paul-Maxwell answered your question

Comment: RE: "here is the print statement for one coulmn" - does it work for you? Don't think so. You need a statement of the form `UPDATE SqlInsertST2 SET [colName] = (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(....)) FROM SqlInsertST2) WHERE [Name] = 'Total'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working use of dynamic SQL. Some things differ to yours (e.g. I prefer to use COALESCE and the use of TRY_CONVERT (see comment by Charlieface) is recommended as it will avoid conversion errors. Vitally it adds the needed prefix and suffix SQL to form a complete select query, and in that suffix all I had to do was include the `WITH ROLLUP` to achieve the totals row.

```
CREATE TABLE SqlInsertST2 (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Class VARCHAR(50),
    Column1 FLOAT,
    Column2 FLOAT,
    Column3 FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO SqlInsertST2 (Id, Class, Column1, Column2, Column3)
VALUES (1, 'A', 10000000, 20000000, 30000000),
       (2, 'A', 40000000, 50000000, 60000000),
       (3, 'B', 70000000, 80000000, 90000000);
```

```
3 rows affected
```

```
DECLARE @sum_query NVARCHAR(MAX)
;
SET @sum_query = N'SELECT COALESCE(class, ''Total'') AS class';
/* Note 1. additional columns if needed can be added in the above */

SELECT @sum_query = @sum_query + N', SUM(COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT,' 
                  + QUOTENAME(column_name) + N'),0)) / 10000000 as ' + QUOTENAME(column_name)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'SqlInsertST2' 
AND ordinal_position > (SELECT ordinal_position 
                        FROM information_schema.columns 
                        WHERE table_name = 'SqlInsertST2'
                        AND column_name = 'Class');
                        
SET @sum_query = @sum_query + N' FROM SqlInsertST2 GROUP BY Class WITH ROLLUP';
/* Note 2. If additional columns added at note 1, also add them here too */


SELECT @sum_query;  -- display the string, for debugging purposes only

EXEC sp_executesql @sum_query;
```

| (this is the generated sql string) |
| --- |
| SELECT COALESCE(class, 'Total') AS class, SUM(COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT,[Column1]),0)) / 10000000 as [Column1], SUM(COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT,[Column2]),0)) / 10000000 as [Column2], SUM(COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT,[Column3]),0)) / 10000000 as [Column3] FROM SqlInsertST2 GROUP BY Class WITH ROLLUP |

| class | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 7 | 9 |
| B | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| Total | 12 | 15 | 18 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VaR8r_TM)

I hope with this answer that you will now understand how important it is to know what the "expected result" is, and to provide some sample data to achieve that result.

Comment: this is the desired output i actually want https://imgur.com/a/yIq4bWn and as part of the test data i have replcaed 10000000 to 10

Comment: I cannot see your images (they are blocked by network policy) PLUS you should ADD this detail into your QUESTION (don't hide it in a comment well down the page). Finally, here is a way to create a simple text table that you paste in the question instead of using an image https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ . I did peek at the image using my phone, there is nothing in that image that changes my answer - all you have to do is include the columns: Name, Roll_no, Email_id, and Class  where in my answer I have just Class. That is something you can definitely do.

Comment: Again, the supplied image does make your question more complete, and thankyou for adding into the question. However all you need to do to extend my answer is include a few more columns into the @sum_query string. You can do this.

Comment: See "**Note 1**" & "**Note 2**" that I just added. All you need to do is add the extra columns into the beginning and end of the @sum_query string. I am not offering to do that as it would also mean re-building the demo table, extra sample data, and frankly you need to understand how it works anyway, so try it, & it will be more satisfying if you add some yourself

Answer (score 1):

To provide you a solution requires more information than just a query. For example it isn't known what you actually require as an output - although we can make some guesses. Additionally it is always helpful to provide some sample data (and the expected result should trace back to that data).

So, to facilitate the process it seems like you want a totals row - but you might not need to use a temp table or an update statement to achieve this, **IF** the following is close to what you are expecting. Here I have used `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP` which will do the totals for me. Note how `ISNULL(class, 'Total') AS class` is used to output the row label "Total" when needed.

```
CREATE TABLE SqlInsertST2 (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Class VARCHAR(50),
    Column1 FLOAT,
    Column2 FLOAT,
    Column3 FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO SqlInsertST2 (Id, Class, Column1, Column2, Column3)
VALUES (1, 'A', 10000000, 20000000, 30000000),
       (2, 'A', 40000000, 50000000, 60000000),
       (3, 'B', 70000000, 80000000, 90000000);
```

```
3 rows affected
```

```
SELECT
      ISNULL(class, 'Total') AS class
    , ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([Column1]) = 1 THEN CONVERT(Float, [Column1]) ELSE 0 END)/10000000, 0) AS Column1
    , ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([Column2]) = 1 THEN CONVERT(Float, [Column2]) ELSE 0 END)/10000000, 0) AS Column2
    , ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC([Column3]) = 1 THEN CONVERT(Float, [Column3]) ELSE 0 END)/10000000, 0) AS Column3
FROM SqlInsertST2
GROUP BY class WITH ROLLUP
```

| class | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 7 | 9 |
| B | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| Total | 12 | 15 | 18 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xztJqeaI)

Comment: how do i use within the dynamic one but

Comment: im trying to sum all the values from the coulmns after a specific coulmn  in my case its 'Class' after sum i want to devide the sum value with 10000000 , thats basically what i need , but what i also want is to update the output in the table itself , in the row where the value in the coulmn 'name' is equals to 'total'

Comment: Group by rollup will automatically add-up each column and add the totals row.  You do not been a temp table or an update. If however you feel there is more to your question provide the sample data and expected result. To the question, not as a comment.

Comment: Also `ISNUMERIC` is a bad idea, it returns true for `.` for example. Just use `TRY_CONVERT`